# Basic Firebase DB writing - version issues (maybe!)

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

I have written a number of apps in the past using Android Studio 2.3.3, Firebase 9.2.0 - no problems it's all very logical.

I have just updated my Android Studio to 3.2.1 and now using Firebase libs 16.0.4 and I cannot talk to my database. I've used Firebase Assistant which tells me I'm connected, I don't seem to get any errors and I've cut down the code so it's just the very basic of writes.

I don't really know where to turn to next, there seem to be a lot of config changes between these versions.

```
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference ref = mDatabase.getReference("Testing");

    ref.child("Item").setValue("Test String");
```

Code with Completion Listener :

```
        Log.e(TAG, "Starting ...");

    FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference ref = db.getReference("Testing");

    ref.child("Richie").setValue("Getting peed off", new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@Nullable DatabaseError databaseError, @NonNull DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
            Log.e(TAG,"They think it's all over ...");

            if (databaseError != null) {
                Log.e(TAG,"ERROR ... " + databaseError.getMessage() );
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG,"All Good  " );
            }
        }
    });

    Log.e(TAG, "... Done");
```

Comment: Have you tried to add a complete listener to see where the problem is? Maybe you don't have sufficient permissions, right?

Comment: @AlexMamo That's interesting, I hadn't tried that. It is a possibility - although I have written to that DB with a different app and my old config. I will try, thx.

Comment: Ok, try it and keep me posted.

Comment: @AlexMamo : I've added a completion listener and still nothing gets fired. I've been a developer for over 30 years, and the code is so simple, I just can't see what is wrong. I'm thinking it is an issue communication to the DB, but the A/S assistant says I'm connected....

Comment: Try to write a simple value to the database. Does it work?

Comment: @AlexMamo - feeling stupid, as I suspected I would, the problem turned out to be that I didn't have any network access on the emulator. Deep in the logcat I saw the message "Could not resolve host" and it was obvious. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It happens. You're welcome, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You Can try to go to Settings/General in Firebase Console and check you SHA1 maybe for some reason the SHA1 in Android Studio is changed with the update also try to update the google.sevices.json file

Comment: Thanks, the google-services file was re-generated, so should be fine, but will check the SHA1

Comment: Is the SHA1 compulsory for testing apps ? I thought it was only release versions that required it. I don't think my old dev projects ever had one until release time.